# File upload with jquery form plugin and mvc 3 is not filling in the target property with my partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm trying to setup a simple file/image upload for a web app I'm working on. To help, I'm using the jquery form plugin found here: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

From the examples, it seems that you define where you want your return data to be placed by defining the "target" property.

So the problem is that instead of rendering the partial inside the defined 'target' location, my whole browser is 'posting back' and I get redirected to the individual partials page.

```
    public PartialViewResult BackgroundImageWindow()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

BackgroundImageWindow.cshtml

```
<div class="divBGImageLoader">


    <form id="FileUploadForm" action='@Url.Action("FileUpload", "SlideShow")' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input id="UploadFileButton" type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>


    <div id="BGImageTable">
        @{Html.RenderAction("BackgroundImageWindowTable");}
    </div>


</div>
```

Which goes here:

```
    public PartialViewResult BackgroundImageWindowTable()
    {

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Content/uploads"));
        List<FileInfo> files = di.GetFiles().ToList();

        return PartialView(files); // returns a partial with a table of the uploaded files
    }
```

javascript:

```
    $("#UploadFileButton").live("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // <- doc file said it needed this
        e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // <- uuh just in case 

        var ajaxSubmitOptions = {
            target: $("#BGImageTable"),
            beforeSubmit: function () {
                //$("#loading").show();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //$("#loading").hide();
            }
        };

        $(this).ajaxSubmit(ajaxSubmitOptions);

        return false; //<- documentation said this was necessary to stop the 'post back'
    });
```

FileUpload Part:

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // Verify that the user selected a file
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // extract only the fielname
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/uploads"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
    }
    // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again

    return RedirectToAction("BackgroundImageWindowTable");
}
```

So like I said previously, this seems to be working except for the fact that the partial is being rendered and displayed like if it was a separate page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should connect to `form` `submit` event instead of `UploadFileButton`. Just like this

```
$("#FileUploadForm").live("submit", function(e){
    // do your stuff here
}
```